# Using Bootstrap to create holy grail style layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Sorry if this question has already been answered, I couldn't find anything that was exactly what I want.

I'm trying to create a responsive layout which is something similar to the [Holy Grail Layout on A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)

There will be a fixed width column on the left, a variable width column in the middle and then a fixed width column on the right. The right column will only be visible in windows that are over a certain width and the whole thing will only expand up to a certain size.

I've created a [jsFiddle which does exactly what I want here](http://jsfiddle.net/XJGFP/).

My basic HTML looks like this:

```
<h1>Window Width: <span></span></h1>
<div id="container">

    <div id="center" class="column">
        <h1>Two</h1>
        <p>Width: <span></span></p>
    </div>

    <div id="left" class="column">
        <h2>One</h2>
        <p>Width: <span></span></p>
    </div>

    <div id="right" class="column">
        <h2>Three</h2>
        <p>Width: <span></span></p>
    </div>

</div>
```

My question is, would it be possible to do this in something like Bootstrap. I think if it is possible then it could save me some time as I need to make it work on mobile devices, however I'm not sure how to combine some fixed and non fixed columns in a single Bootstrap layout.

Comment: Did you ever get this working reliably in Bootstrap 3?

Comment: No, I just ended up doing it without Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had need of a Bootstrap holy grail layout (3 responsive columns, with the center column first in the source ordering, where any column can have the longest content).

Original markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

     <div id="center">
       ...
       center column content
       ...
     </div>

    <div id="left">
       ...
       left column content
       ...
    </div>

    <div id="right">
       ...
       right column content
       ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By adding a set of `-inset-` (margin-right) mixins/classes to complement the Bootstrap `-offset-` (margin-left) mixins/classes, I could achieve the layout by using these with an extra wrapping `div` around the center column content.

Decorated markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div id="center" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-inset--12">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-md-inset-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-inset-2">
         ...
         center column content
         ...
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="left" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
       ...
       left column content
       ...
    </div>

    <div id="right" class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
       ...
       right column content
       ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3n5Lvr84/

The idea is that the center column is 100% width with a -100% right-hand margin, bringing the left and right columns to the top of the center column, and the center column inner element makes room for the columns with `-offset-` and `-inset-` margins.

I have included the full set of compiled `-inset-` rules in the CSS of the fiddle; you need 0-12 as in the `-offset-` rules as well as a -12 for the center column outer element. The left and right hand column source ordering can be switching by changing the element that is `float:right`.

Finally, I find it tidier using the mixins. Here are the SASS-flavoured inset mixins created by repurposing Bootstrap's `mixins\_grid.scss`. The LESS mixins and `mixins\_grid-frameword.scss` can be similarly repurposed if you prefer to use the markup & class-based Bootstrap responsive grid and/or LESS.

`_inset.scss`

```
@mixin make-xs-column-inset($columns) {
  margin-right: percentage(($columns / $grid-columns));
}
@mixin make-sm-column-inset($columns) {
  @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    margin-right: percentage(($columns / $grid-columns));
  }
}
@mixin make-md-column-inset($columns) {
  @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
    margin-right: percentage(($columns / $grid-columns));
  }
}
@mixin make-lg-column-inset($columns) {
  @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
    margin-right: percentage(($columns / $grid-columns));
  }
}
```

Holy grail layout for the original markup at the top of the post (once the wrapping div has been added to `#center`):

`_holygrail.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "_inset.scss";

#center {
  @include make-xs-column(12);
  @include make-sm-column-inset(-12);
  > div {
    @include make-sm-column-offset(3);
    @include make-md-column-offset(3);
    @include make-md-column-inset(3);
    @include make-lg-column-offset(2);
    @include make-lg-column-inset(2);
  }
}

#left {
  @include make-xs-column(12);
  @include make-sm-column(3);
  @include make-lg-column(2);
}

#right {
  @include make-xs-column(12);
  @include make-md-column(3);
  @include make-lg-column(2);
}

.container #right {
  float:right;
}
```

Credit for the non-responsive holy grail layout idea used (Tanfa flexi_floats) to https://stackoverflow.com/users/669044/clairesuzy

Comment: JS Fiddle achieving submitter's desired behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/rbgb6apd/